# Ubuntu 12.04 - Thunderbird 17.0.2 - Set MIME enconding quoted printable

Tags: thunderbird, mime-type

**Ubuntu 12.04 - Thunderbird 17.0.2**

How can I set the MIME enconding = "**quoted printable**" for messages containing 8-bit characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open config editor (preferences, advanced, general, config editor button)
search for
mail.strictly_mime
then make it true
(which sends messages that contain 8-bit characters as quoted-printable)